# in which file can i change the value of magic_quotes_gpc = 0 in PHP

Tags: php

In which file can I change the value of

```
magic_quotes_gpc = 0
```

in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't!  Magic quotes have been deprecated; they are a security risk.  See http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php.

Comment: Open a command prompt and run `php --ini`

Comment: Oli Charlesworth - You seem to have inferred that he wants to change the value of the directive from 0, but it seems ambiguous to me whether he wants to change it from 0 or to 0.

Comment: @Hammerite change the value of 0 sounds pretty much like *from* to me

Comment: The way he phrases it, he could mean "change the value of magic_quotes_gpc, which is currently 0" or he could mean "change the value of magic_quotes_gpc, so that it is 0"

Comment: @Hammerite no, it doesnt. The OP (how do you know the OP is a "he" btw) asks to change the value **of** `mqgpc = 0` and not change the value of `mqgpc` **to** 0. The `=` does not imply **to**. But then again, it doesnt matter for the answer anyway.

Comment: @Gordon, I disagree. To me his statement could mean either of the two interpretations. Regarding the use of "he", gender is unknown, in which case I default to use of "he".

Comment: @Hammerite then we have to agree to disagree because the **to** reading is impossible IMO. It clearly reads value **of** `<codeblock>`. But like I said, it doesnt matter, so let's stop the quibbling :)

Comment: Gordon, one reason why I can see how you might interpret the sentence the way you do is that in C-like languages there is this notion of assignments being themselves expressions that return a value. To someone versed in this way of thinking, it's natural to parse the sentence thus: magic_quotes_gpc is 0 (it's asserted), and it's this value which is to be changed. To me the sentence is to be read as an English sentence, in which capacity it's syntactically broken. Taking an open-minded view of what the sentence (qua sentence) could mean, it's hard to tell, which is why I say it could be either.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file is `php.ini`. The actual configuration value you're looking for is `magic_quotes_gpc`

On linux/unix systems it's usually

```
/etc/php.ini
```

On windows it's dependent on the installation path, so you'll have to search for it.

Comment: i have installed xampp on windows. i have almost all files. still not able to locate. please help

Comment: On Windows, it's usually in `C:\PHP\php.ini` (or `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini`; wherever you've installed PHP).

Comment: with xampp it's normally in `your/path/to/xampp/php/php.ini`.

Comment: i have searched in php.ini. i am not able to find this.

Comment: The actual configuration value you're looking for is `magic_quotes_gpc`, not `magic_gpc_quotes`

Comment: i did searched for magic_quotes_gpc in php.ini. the option i get is to change the values ON and OFF. but i want to change magic_gpc_quotes = 1 0r magic_gpc_quotes = 0.

Comment: `Off` is equivalent to `0` here (and `On` to `1`).

Comment: but i want to change the value of magic_gpc_quotes to 0(Zero).

Comment: @gourav No you don't. There is no such option. You want to change "magic_quotes_gpc".

Answer (score 0):

Beside on `php.ini` you can also change `magic_quotes_gpc` by using `.htaccess`. Put following line on your `.htaccess`:

```
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
```